# How do I add custom meta tags for each route in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, meta-tags

I know how to add custom titles to each route, but how do I add meta tags to each route in Flutter web? Thanks

Comment: Im trying to achieve the same. no luck so far. did you make it?